# Python - Automating Filling Of Excel Online Spreadsheet

Tags: python, automation

I am trying to automate populating an online Excel sheet (the Microsoft equivalent of Google Sheets) with a Python script but have not found any resource available online regarding a direct way of doing this.

Would anyone know if there is a specific Python library or API that would help with this?

Thanks.

R.

Comment: Check this https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

Answer (score -1):

If everything else fails, you can always try using [`Selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) with python.

Will allow you programmatically interact with a real browser.

Comment: I guess the author wants to use it in a backend. An API access would be a far better approach.